# C++ how to move files and copy them from one disk to different without the usage of winapi?

Tags: c++, winapi, copy, system, move

It must be pure **c++**, I know about system(`"copy c:\\test.txt d:\\test.txt"`); but I think it's the system function, not **c++** solution, or I can mistakes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `std::fstream`? Open one for reading and another for writing, and use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) to let the standard library handle the copying.

Something like this:

```
void copy_file(const std::string &from, const std::string &to)
{
    std::ifstream is(from, ios::in | ios::binary);
    std::ofstream os(to, ios::out | ios::binary);

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(is), std::istream_iterator<char>(),
              std::ostream_iterator<char>(os));
}
```

Comment: It can't be compiled because istream_iterator and ostream_iterator are class templates which require template arguments list.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `copy_file` from [boost](http://boost.org).

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

boost::filesystem::copy_file("c:\\test.txt","d:\\test.txt");
```

It will throw an exception if there is an error. See this page for more documentation: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#copy_file

Answer (score 2):

I like the simple streaming approach, using standard STL operators:

```
std::ifstream ifs("somefile", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream ofs("newfile", std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
ofs << ifs.rdbuf();
```

The idea here is that there is an `operator<< (streambuf*)` for `std::ofstream`, so you simply pass it the `streambuf` associated with your input stream.

For completeness, you could do something like the following:

```
bool exists(const std::string& s) {
    std::ifstream istr(s, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    return istr.is_open();
}

void copyfile(const std::string& from, const std::string& to) {
    if (!exists(to)) {
        std::ifstream ifs(from, std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
        std::ofstream ofs(to, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
        ofs << ifs.rdbuf();
    }
}
```

This would only copy the file if the destination didn't already exist. Just an extra check for sanity :)

Regarding moving a file, in "standard" C++ I would probably copy the file (as above), and then delete it, doing something like:

```
if (0 != remove(from.c_str())) {
    // remove failed
}
```

Aside from using something like `boost` I'm not convinced there's another standard, portable way to delete a file.

Comment: Will it works with anyfile or only txt preferences? What if I need to move .mp3 for example from C:\song.mp3 to D:\song.mp3 will it works?

Comment: It should work for any file-type. Just in case, I'll alter the example to read the file as binary.